# Dynamic Step Addition/Removal in sap.m.Wizard

Tags: sapui5

I have a wizard with 2 steps. I want to add/remove steps to the wizard based on user selection in second step and update the wizard (add more steps to wizard or remove steps). I am unable to correctly render my view once I try to remove a step from the wizard. When I remove a step, I lose my entire view and the wizard appears as blank with no steps.

1. I Tried using `bindAggregation` and added wizard step as template
2. I tried to add a step using method `addWizardStep`.

**My view:**

```xml
<Wizard id="idCOEWizard" complete="wizardCompletedHandler" steps="{wizardSteps>/steps}" showNextButton="false">
    <WizardStep id="idCOESteps" title="{wizardSteps>stepTitle}" validated="{wizardSteps>validated}" activate="onStepActivate">
        <core:Fragment fragmentName="" type="XML"/>
        <core:Fragment fragmentName="" type="XML"/>
        <core:Fragment fragmentName="" type="XML"/>
    </WizardStep>
</Wizard>
```

**Steps data:**

```js
{
    "steps": [{
        "id": "EmployeeDetails",
        "stepTitle": "Employee Details",
        "validated": true,
        "sortOrder": 1,
        "viewFrag": "EmployeeDetails"
    }, {
        "id": "TypeofChange",
        "stepTitle": "Type of Change",
        "validated": true,
        "sortOrder": 2,
        "viewFrag": "TypeOfChange"
    }]
}
```

**Code:**

```js
var aCurrentSteps = this.getView().getModel("wizardSteps").getProperty("/steps");
var oWizardSteps = this.byId("idCOESteps");
for (var i = 0; i < aCurrentSteps.length; i++) {
    if (sStep === aCurrentSteps[i].id) {
      aCurrentSteps.splice(i);
    }
}
this.byId("idCOEWizard").removeAllSteps();
this.byId("idCOEWizard").bindAggregation("steps", {
    path: "{wizardSteps>/steps}",
    template: oWizardSteps
});
this.byId("idCOEWizard").discardProgress(this.byId("idCOEWizard").getSteps()[0]);
this.getView().getModel("wizardSteps").refresh(true);
```